# Update Table from a Form using cmd button

Tags: vba, ms-access

Okay i would like to be able to update part attributes table from a form. The Part_ID in table (primary key) is listed in combo box in form (prtnum_cbo) this carries a list of attributes that can be loaded into form, from the table SawPartNumber. I found code that works to Add a new record to table below. But I can not find anything on how to update or edit the record in table linked to Part_ID / prtnum_cbo. Using same logic as add new i can edit.. but only the 1st record in table updates

```
Private Sub svprt_cmd_Click()
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    
        Dim db As Database
        Dim rec As Recordset

        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from SawPartNumber")

        rec.AddNew
        rec("Part_ID") = Me.prtnum_cbo
        rec("Rev") = Me.rev_txt
        rec("Tool Type") = Me.tool_cbo
        rec("Tool Diameter") = Me.TDia_txt
        rec("Wing count") = Me.tip_cnt_txt
        rec("Saw Style") = Me.styl_cbo
        rec("Kerf") = Me.kerf_txt
        rec("Tip style") = Me.tips_cbo
        rec("Tip grade") = Me.tipg_txt
        rec("Hook") = Me.hook_txt
        rec("OD cl") = Me.odcl_txt
        rec("Radial") = Me.radin_txt
        rec("Back") = Me.backin_txt
        rec("Drop") = Me.drop_txt
        rec("Top Bvl") = Me.tpbvl_txt
        rec("Cnr Brk") = Me.cnrbk_txt
        rec("K Lnd") = Me.klnd_txt
        rec("Tooth Style Count") = Me.tscnt_txt
        rec("Special Notes") = Me.prtnts_txt
        rec("Tooth style") = Me.toos_txt
   
        rec.Update

        Set rec = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
 
Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "Part already exists"

    Resume Error_Handler_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: Open recordset filtered to desired record for edit. Should post code attempt for Edit, not AddNew. Why code to add or edit? Why not a bound form?

Comment: Kind of complicated I know. But this is a "Sub" Table to the Form that only feeds combo box for part numbers and several attributes for that part. Another table is already bound to the form for another record to be kept for different reason. Idea is to have one Form for our users

Comment: One form in a db would be highly unusual. I have one very small db that appears to have only one form as far as user is concerned but is actually a form/subform/subsubform arrangement. Doesn't alter my comment that you show code for AddNew but say you need Edit. What have you attempted trying to resolve issue? Also, what you describe in comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: Code should be in question, not comment. Edit question.